# SyntaxWarning Python noob gets error

Tags: python

I was programming a simple game and when I tried to run the program it said :
SyntaxWarning: name 'apples' is used prior to global declaration

Here is my code. I was wondering if someone could tell me why!

```
import time
global gold
global apples
apples = 0
gold = 0

def start():
    print ("Hello and welcome to apples, made by Rahul Mathilakath")
    name = input ("What's your name: ")
    print ("Welcome " + name + "!")
    print ("The objective of the game is to collect apples and then sell them to earn gold.")
    choice = input ("Do you want to play? Y/N ")
    if choice == "Y":
        print ("Let's get started!")
        Game()
    if choice == "N":
        print ("Okay bye ...")
def Game():
    global apples
    global gold
    pick = input ("Do you want to pick an apple? Y/N ")
    if pick == "Y":
        time.sleep(1)
        print ("You picked an apple.")
        apple=apples+1
        print ("You have ",apples," apples.")
        Game()
    if pick == "N":
        sell = input ("Do you want to sell you apples? Y/N")
        if sell == "Y":
            global gold
            global apples
            print ("You currently have ",apples," apples")
            print ("You have sold your apples")
            gold = apples*5
            apples = 0
            Game()
        if sell == "N":
            Game()
```

Thank you for your help! Sorry if the answer is super simple I am a very new to this!

Answer (score 1):

You have the words

```
global gold
global apples
```

appearing twice in your `Game()` function. You only need to declare something as global once per scope. Since you've declared them global right away in `Game()`, you don't need to do so again in that function. That should eliminate that syntax warning.

Comment: It's also at the top of the file, so 3 times

Comment: Thanks you. My mistake I didn't realize the problem was occurring there.

Comment: On that note, do you need to declare a variable as `global` if you're initializing it in the global environment, outside of any function? I think that's implied. So the `global` declaration at the very top can also be safely discarded. You should only use `global` when you're in a function and you want to change the global variable, instead of a local one.

Comment: You shall declare use of `global` inside of the function as soon as possible. Even if you declare the `global` later on, it makes the variable globally declare from very first statement in given function. The practice to put `global` at the top of function shall prevent some surprises.

Answer (score 0):

instead of using "global", run a function and then return that function as your number, from inside the function. for instance...

#

```
def add_one():
    return 1

number = input('enter a number')
number = number + add_one()
```

#

you have returned the value, which defines the function as 1

i once learnt this in the middle of a test, so it really stuck with me :D

another tip is to do if answer[0] == 'y':, because then the person could answer anything from y, yes, or yeseroony and as long as it starts with a lower case y, it would still continue. if you wanted to convert it to lowercase, you could do answer.lower() and then continue.

a bit off topic, but i hope it helped!